# Parallelism with C++ unordered_map

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, unordered-map

I have an unordered_map of type `std::unordered_map<std::string, int64_t> sMap`. This contains a number of strings and a 'weight' associated with each of them. I want to find the strings with the N largest weights.

If I wanted to do this using a single thread, I think I could create a priority queue of pairs like this

```
std::priority_queue<
    std::pair<std::string, int64_t>,
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int64_t>>,
    std::function<bool(std::pair<std::string, int64_t>&,
            std::pair<std::string, int64_t>&)>> prQ(comparePair);
```

and just go through the whole unordered_map, inserting elements to prQ while maintaining length N.

I want to achieve the same using multiple threads. I was thinking of assigning each thread to work on a few elements of the unordered_map to create a local priority queue of length N which can be merged into a global one at the end.

The problem I am facing right now is that the iterator which I get from unordered_map::begin() does not work with a `+` operator. At least that is the error that I am getting :
`error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘std::unordered_map<std::basic_string<char>, long int>::iterator {aka std::__detail::_Node_iterator<std::pair<const std::b
asic_string<char>, long int>, false, true>}’ and ‘int’)`
Thus, I cannot really specify a range of elements to be worked upon by a particular thread. The `[]` operator would take a key as expected and not an offset.

Essentially, I can't seem to find a way to have a data parallel loop that would work with only a few elements per thread. How can I solve this problem using multiple threads then?

EDIT : @Brian Vandberg asked me to supply a simplified example of the code that generates the error I was talking about.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, int64_t> sMap;
//Initialize sMap values
int start = 0, end = 2;
for(auto i = sMap.begin() + start; sMap.begin() + end; ++i) {
    std::cout<<i->first<<"\t"<<i->second<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for [std::advance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance)

Comment: You might want to supply a simplified example of the  code that's generating the error.

Comment: @BrianVandenberg I have updated my post with the simplified code.

Comment: @LokiAstari I don't know yet, but I will look into it. Thanks!

Comment: map/unordered map aren't like vectors.  There's no implied ordering.  The most intuitive definition for operator+ behavior, based on what you're trying to do, is probably "iterate `n` times, then return the iterator" ... however, if I had to guess they didn't implement `operator+` for map/unordered map iterators because they don't want users to begin thinking of it like an array of things instead of an *unordered* collection of things.

Comment: Furthermore, due to the unordered nature of those collections, attempting to iterate in the manner you are is essentially the same as iterating in an unspecified order, but only iterating a fixed number of times.

Comment: @BrianVandenberg That makes total sense to me that there is a lack of ordering in this container. Regardless, it makes parallel access a bit difficult to achieve. And yes, I am not really interested in going from one element to another(order) but rather accessing a part of the elements.

Comment: What about using the iterator pattern?  Make your own class to wrap your map/unordered map, where your iterator doles out instances from the map in a thread-safe manner.

Comment: Even though the order is unspecified, it will be consistent across multiple iterations (assuming the map is unchanged between them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'm not sure that I'd go with a priority queue for this problem (either single threaded, or as the part performed by a specific thread). The standard library has [`nth_element`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/nth_element/), which you can use to find the *n*th element in linear time. Following that, finding which elements are larger is also linear time.

You might consider this if speed is the problem, yours if size is a problem (`nth_element` will effectively force you to create a copy of the data). In this solution you iterate over the map (or part of it), and `push_back` only the weights into a `vector`, on which you perform `nth_element`. In the 2nd stage, loop again over the map, and choose those whose weight is higher.

---

Suppose you have the loop:

```
std::size_t j = 0;
for(const auto &e: sMap)
{
    if(++j % k != i)
        continue;
    // Rest of code goes here.
}
```

Then if you use it for the *i*th thread out of *k*, it will partition the elements between the threads. Moreover, while all threads are iterating over the same elements (if only to skip most of them), it's happening in parallel.

---

Each thread can generate its candidates for the largest *m* elements, then choose the largest *m* elements from the *km* candidates using the method above (with the `nth_element`) or any other method.

It's interesting to ask what size of `sMap` will generate any speedup in practice.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this. The reason I am not sure about nth element is because I think the requirement is that I should pass a random access iterator to the function. An unordered_map does not have that because it lacks an order.

Comment: I think the intent is to use `nth_element` and a `vector` (or possibly `deque`) in place of your `priority_queue`, not in place of your `unordered_map`. (I'm not sure how it'd work though.)

Comment: @user19448 celticminstrel is correct. See update to the 1st part. (Note that the 2nd and 3rd parts are orthogonal in any case, though.)

Comment: Both the approaches that you have mentioned should be a good fit for my problem statement. Thanks for your response.